# Apache configuration: Setting a different alias based on a cookie

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd.conf

Is it possible to  set a different alias based on whether a cookie is present? What I am trying to achieve is: use a different folder to display different content based on whether a cookie has been set in my browser, whilst keeping all the URL paths the same. Something like:

```
if(COOKIE=foo & value=val)
  alias /x /y
else
  alias /x /z
```

Any suggestions welcome

Thank you kindly!
Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ***
RewriteRule /x(.*) /y$1 [L]
#else 
RewriteRule /x(.*) /z$1 [L]
```

Replace *** with the correct thing you want to match - see [How do I make RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} match a cookie value exactly?](https://serverfault.com/questions/499246/how-do-i-make-rewritecond-http-cookie-match-a-cookie-value-exactly)

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. Thank you very much